# How to read/write photo subject tags defined by user

Tags: java, android, image, metadata, jpeg

Hi I am relatively new to Android and have searched until have a headache over the last few days (time for a coffee).  PC programs such as digiKam (Linux) allow you to tag photos with keywords.  You can later search these images for matches in these keywords.

I have had a look at [Metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) and see that it can read these types of tags to XMP or IPTC directories within the photo.

Does anyone have a nice simple example on how to do this?  I am just interested in the reading/writing of the tag as the searching is relatively straight forward.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after a good coffee I spotted the answer after a bit of trial and error.

To read tags from the Xmp directory hidden in the metadata of an image using Metadata-extractor I used the following code....

```
private void metadataMetaEx (File jpegFile)
{

    Metadata metadata = null;
    String tagInfo = null;
    XmpDirectory xmpDirectory = null;
    Map<String, String> xmp = null; 

    // Get all the metadata of the file
    try {
        metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);
    } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Read in the metadata of the xmp directory
    try
    {
        xmpDirectory = metadata.getDirectory(XmpDirectory.class);
    } catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Look through the xmp metadata for keys containing the word "Subject" and if a match add the value to the variable tagInfo
    if (xmpDirectory != null)
    {
        xmp = xmpDirectory.getXmpProperties();
        Iterator tags = xmp.keySet().iterator();
        tagInfo = "Image Tags: ";           
        while (tags.hasNext())
        {
            String key=(String)tags.next();

            if (key.contains("Subject"))
            {
                String value=(String)xmp.get(key);
                tagInfo += value
                        += "; ";                    
            }

        }           
    } }
```

This will put all tags in the string variable infoTag that you can use elsewhere